# Will relative entropy increase with majorization?

Tags: inequalities, it.information-theory

Suppose that three probability distributions have the relation $P\succ Q\succ R$, then do the following relations between their relative entropy valid? (assume that $p_1\geq p_2\geq\cdots \geq p_n$ and so do Q and R)

$D(P||Q)\leq D(P||R),\;\; D(Q||P)\leq D(R||P)$, where $D$ is the relative entropy.

Comment: Yes, this result is true and follows from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality  (since relative entropy is convex in both arguments)

Comment: @Suvrit: Really? In Karamata's inequality, the identical functions are used for every $x_i$, but here is different. I was failed to prove it by Karamata's inequality and I don't have counterexamples. Here the majorization relation      between the entire three distributions are important.

Comment: ah ok! so maybe this inequality does not hold, or do you have reason to believe that these hold?

Comment: How about this counterexample: P = [10,6,2,2]*(1/20), Q = [8,4,4,4]*(1/20) and R = [8 - $\epsilon$, 4 + $\epsilon$,4,4] where $\epsilon$ is small, say, 0.001. Here $D(P||Q) = 0.0946$ and $D(P||R) = 0.0943$.